# AVExportSession exporting video super slow

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I am trying to simply increase the speed of my exporting of my merged video.

Here is the code: //from my extensive research online and on SO, I have pretty much come down to the preset PassThrough makes it super fast, however as I wrote in a comment in the code, my merging code does not seem to work with that preset for export :/

```
            static func videoCompositionInstruction(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset)
            -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
                let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
                let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]

                let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
                let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)

                var scaleToFitRatio = 1080 / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
                if assetInfo.isPortrait {
                    scaleToFitRatio = 1080 / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
                    let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
                    var finalTransform = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
                    //was needed in my case (if video not taking entire screen and leaving some parts black - don't know when actually needed so you'll have to try and see when it's needed)
                    if assetInfo.orientation == .rightMirrored || assetInfo.orientation == .leftMirrored {
                        finalTransform = finalTransform.translatedBy(x: -transform.ty, y: 0)
                    }
                    instruction.setTransform(finalTransform, at: CMTime.zero)
                } else {
                    let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
                    var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
                        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
                    if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                        let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                        let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                        let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                        let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
                        concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
                    }
                    instruction.setTransform(concat, at: CMTime.zero)
                }

                return instruction
        }

        static func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform)
            -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
                var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
                var isPortrait = false
                if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
                    assetOrientation = .right
                    isPortrait = true
                } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
                    assetOrientation = .rightMirrored
                    isPortrait = true
                } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
                    assetOrientation = .left
                    isPortrait = true
                } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
                    assetOrientation = .leftMirrored
                    isPortrait = true
                } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
                    assetOrientation = .up
                } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
                    assetOrientation = .down
                }
                return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
        }

    func mergeVideosTestSQ(arrayVideos:[AVAsset], completion:@escaping (URL?, Error?) -> ()) {
            
            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            
            var instructions: [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction] = []
            var insertTime = CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1)

            /// for each URL add the video and audio tracks and their duration to the composition
            for sourceAsset in arrayVideos {
                    
                let frameRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1), duration: sourceAsset.duration)

                guard
                    let nthVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)),
                    let nthAudioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)), //0 used to be kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid
                    let assetVideoTrack = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first
                else {
                    print("didnt work")
                    return
                }

                var assetAudioTrack: AVAssetTrack?
                assetAudioTrack = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first
                print(assetAudioTrack, ",-- assetAudioTrack???", assetAudioTrack?.asset, "<-- hes", sourceAsset)
                
                do {
                    
                    try nthVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(frameRange, of: assetVideoTrack, at: insertTime)
                    try nthAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(frameRange, of: assetAudioTrack!, at: insertTime)
    
                    //instructions:
                    let nthInstruction = MainCamVC.videoCompositionInstruction(nthVideoTrack, asset: sourceAsset)
                    nthInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: CMTimeAdd(insertTime, sourceAsset.duration)) //sourceasset.duration

                    instructions.append(nthInstruction)
                    insertTime = insertTime + sourceAsset.duration //sourceAsset.duration

                    
                    
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("didnt wor2k")
                    }
                }

            }
        

            let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1), duration: insertTime)

            mainInstruction.layerInstructions = instructions

            let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
            mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
            mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920)

            let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merge.mp4")

            //below to clear the video form docuent folder for new vid...
            let fileManager = FileManager()
            try? fileManager.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)
            
        
            /// try to start an export session and set the path and file type
            if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) { //DOES NOT WORK WITH AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
                exportSession.outputFileType = .mov
                exportSession.outputURL = outputFileURL
                exportSession.videoComposition = mainComposition
                exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

                /// try to export the file and handle the status cases
                exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
                    if let url = exportSession.outputURL{
                      completion(url, nil)
                  }
                    if let error = exportSession.error {
                      completion(nil, error)
                  }
                }
                
            }

        }
```

Note I have instructions in order to preserve correct orientations.

Thanks for any help! I just need it to be faster, it roughly takes videoDuration/2 seconds to export in time to export...

Comment: Could you provide sample project, so I can easily test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After implementing your code into my project, it seems what is making your export slow, would be the way you handle the renderSize, as well as the resolution of the video. On top of that perhaps using a lower preset of quality may make it higher.

Specicially I would note this part:

```
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1), duration: insertTime)

    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = instructions

    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920)
```

Changing the renderSize to = the videoCompositions.size (may be different name for your project) does the trick.

Then in the exporting place, I suggest changing this part:

```
    /// try to start an export session and set the path and file type
    if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) { //DOES NOT WORK WITH AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mov
        exportSession.outputURL = outputFileURL
        exportSession.videoComposition = mainComposition
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        /// try to export the file and handle the status cases
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            if let url = exportSession.outputURL{
              completion(url, nil)
          }
            if let error = exportSession.error {
              completion(nil, error)
          }
        }
        
    }
```

As I said before, change it to presetQuality one lower or so. It will vastly improve the speed! Some transformations were also duplicated as well, something to look out for!

Comment: hmm this seems to be working! let me further test, then I will award! :) I will let you know!

Comment: alright! it seems like it did improve my speed, it is now consisntely under a second, I tested on a iphoneX btw... videos ranging form 10-20seconds with multiple merges

Comment: Hi @KevWats I have the same need as you, and the same problems, especially slow rendering.

But in my case I have problems if I use "preferredTimescale: 1" because it's too low, and also I didn't understand what you put inside "mainComposition.renderSize". Could you please help me?